# RecyclerView выбор элементов переход в отдельный Layout

Tags: android, activity, recyclerview, android-layout

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = "RecycleViewAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecycleViewAdapter (Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mImageNames, ArrayList<String> mImages) {
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.material, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(holder.image1);

        holder.image_name.setText(mImageNames.get(position));

        holder.parent_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on " + mImageNames.get(position));

                Toast.makeText(mContext, mImageNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image1;
        TextView image_name;
        RelativeLayout parent_layout;
        public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            image_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            parent_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}



public class Material extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Material";

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.materials);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        initImageBitmaps();
    }
    private void initImageBitmaps(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: preparing bitmaps");
        //1
        mImageUrls.add("https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2015/01/17/589833/ae71f6d11c0ad38688daa0e17dd9b8be.jpg");
        mNames.add("Біологічна та загальна хімія");
        //2
        mImageUrls.add("https://ukrinnovate.com/upload/website-science-or-innovation-article-image-201803191200.jpg");
        mNames.add("Гістологія");
        //3
        mImageUrls.add("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/36spQsZ5pqQ/maxresdefault.jpg");
        mNames.add("Загальної гігієна та екологія");
        //4
        mImageUrls.add("https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/kletki_mikrobiologiya_struktura_113059_1920x1080.jpg");
        mNames.add("Мікробіологія");


        initRecyclerView();
    }
    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recycleview.");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
        RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

Использую RecycleView хочу что бы для каждого элемента было отдельное окно экрана.Но не могу понять как это можно реализовать в данном коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите переходить в разные activity или fragmentы по нажатию на разные элементы `RecyclerView`

В качестве примера приведу свой adapter.

```
public class SearchCitiesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchCitiesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public TextView citySelectedTV;

    private List<City> cities;
    private Context ctx;

    public SearchCitiesAdapter(List<City> cities, Context ctx) {
        this.cities = cities;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_cities, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchCitiesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final City city = cities.get(position);
        holder.textViewCity.setText(city.getTitle());
        holder.textViewFullCity.setText(city.getFullCity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cities.size();
    }




    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewCity;
        public TextView textViewFullCity;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCity);
            textViewFullCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullCity);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    City city =(City)cities.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    String title = "Был выбран населенный пункт: "+city.getTitle();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,title,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(ctx).selectCity(city);


                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Посмотрите на `itemView`. Для него мы повесили слушатель, и в методе `OnClick` вы можете уже реализовать в завимимости от значения чего-то с помощью switch переходить на разные activity (fragments).

Для получения индекса элемента, по которому кликнули, был использован `getAdapterPosition`

Answer (score 3):

У вас в RecyclerAdaptor'e  в методе OnBindViewHolder уже вешается слушатель на нажатие.

```
 holder.parent_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on " + mImageNames.get(position));

            Toast.makeText(mContext, mImageNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Тут сообщение выводится в лог и всплывает информация на экране. В этом блоке вам можно реализовать запуск новой активности. Создайте новую Activity и запустите с помощью startActivity()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ***Имя вашей активности***.class);                 
             view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Скорее всего вам понадобятся несколько Activity для разных элементов. Понять какую из них нужно запускать можно по идентификатору position.
В итоге у вас получится примерно такая конструкция

```
holder.parent_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on " + mImageNames.get(position));

                Toast.makeText(mContext, mImageNames.get(position), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                switch (position) {

                case 0:
                      Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ***Имя вашей активности_1***.class);                 
                      view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                      break;
                case 1:
                      Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ***Имя вашей активности_2***.class);                 
                      view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                      break;

                  ..... и т.д.
```

Comment: break;   забыли поставить

Comment: и с нуля счёт начинается вроде бы

Comment: @VladBulan исправил